# Catching every Exception except for AsyncException

Tags: haskell, exception

I need to execute many computations that might fail in multiple unimaginable ways but the failures can be ignored (user is notified). However, I don’t want to ignore `AsyncException`s like `UserInterrupt` so the user could stop the program using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

If I try to abort the program below, it will just output `# failed: user interrupt` – as if the exception could not be cast to `AsyncException`. From `user interrupt` being printed we know the exception is `UserInterrupt` which can be cast (`cast UserInterrupt :: Maybe AsyncException`).

Why is the `UserInterrupt` exception **not** discerned and **re-thrown**?

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Data.Typeable

main = forM_ [1..500000] processNumber

processNumber n =
    handle h (simulateComputation n)
  where
    h (SomeException e) =
        case (cast e :: Maybe AsyncException) of
            Just ae ->
                throw ae
            Nothing ->
                putStrLn $ show n ++ " failed: " ++ show e

simulateComputation n = do
    putStrLn "...Obtaining data and computing..."
    --when (n `mod` 1000 == 0) $
    --    throw (ErrorCall "ComputationFailed")
    --when (n `mod` 1111 == 0) $
    --    throw DivideByZero
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a dark corner of the language. Actually the `AsyncException` is wrapped into `SomeAsyncException` when it is [converted to `SomeException`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Exception.html#asyncExceptionToException). Use [`asyncExceptionFromException`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:asyncExceptionFromException) instead of `cast` (or cast to `SomeAsyncException`).